# Start или awake для асинхронной загрузки - что лучше?

Tags: unity3d

Куда лучше впихнуть всякую инициализацию что бы загрузка сцены асинхронно работала лучше?

т.е. что бы после появления сцены уже ничего не висло

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У Unity есть [официальный мануал](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html) по порядку выполнению этих методов. Прочитайте что и когда выполняется. Хотя, по сути, разницы никакой нет. Awake вызывается сразу после создания, но до возврата из метода Instantite, Start вызывается перед первым обработанным объектом кадром.